# JQuery: how to split textbox value in parts at every ',' and set it's value in other textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in which I have lastname, firstname and ID. lastname field will suggest auto complete in format "lastname,firstname,ID". This is working fine, but somehow function for split it is not firing 
code for taking input is

```
<tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" id="subscriberLastName" name="subscriberLastName"/></td></tr>
```

JQuery function for spliting the input and storing in three parts is

```
    <script>
$( function()
    {
$('#subscriberLastName').blur(function(){
    var nameParts = $('#subscriberLastName').val().split(',');
    $( '#subscriberLastName' ).val( nameParts[0] );
    $( '#subscriberFirstName' ).val( nameParts[1] );
    $( '#subscriberMember_ID' ).val( nameParts[2] );
} );
} );

</script>
```

Please help, I don't think the problem is with spliting, The function itself is not firing

Thank you very much

Comment: just checking , but did you tab out out of the textbox to another control so that blur has a chance to fire?

Comment: Your code is fine and working for me see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJrxs/)

Comment: @Code Uniquely: I actually want my text box value to change as soon as "lastname,firstname,id" enters the textbox, be it click, tab out or any other method.....can you suggest any other method, which is more effectively. My main purpose is to is to suggest autocomplete lastname, and based on the last name selection, I would like to auto fill firstname and Id and DOB, but I couldn't find good example...can you suggest me something regarding that

Comment: @Satpal: Yes I know, it was working fine with my previous jsp, but somehow it is not working with the new jsp, although the functionality and the code of the both jsp is more or less same.Can you think of any other reason, which can result in this abbration?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
$('#subscriberLastName').blur(function(){
        var nameParts = $('#subscriberLastName').val();
        var arr=[];arr=nameParts.split(',')
        $( '#subscriberLastName' ).val( arr[0] );
        $( '#subscriberFirstName' ).val( arr[1] );
        $( '#subscriberMember_ID' ).val( arr[2] );
    } );
```

The fiddle is

http://jsfiddle.net/LgKUk/3/

Comment: Thank You
works fine but please can you tell me what is the difference between this code and my code?

Comment: the reason you splitting from a initialization so full value not come to your variable so first store in variable then split it

Answer (score -1):

Also check whether you have included the jquery js file in your html. because your code is fine.

Comment: This must be a comment.